# How can I fully remove/delete Ubuntu One?

Tags: delete

I deleted Ubuntu One over 2 weeks ago and today it began downloading my files to Ubuntu One!  I checked and it does not show in my installed programs.  How can I delete Ubuntu One?

I do not want it, I do not like it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's easy. Just run the following in a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone*
```

Comment: Welcome. I hope the answer helped you.